# Cookie is not recognized when parts added on url (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Below are the two functions I currently use inorder to read and create my cookie (cookie should only be valid for 1 day)

```
function set1DayValidationCookie(){
     var d = new Date();
     var today = d.getMonth() + '' + d.getDate();

     if (readCookie('onedaycookie') != today) {
         document.cookie = 'onedaycookie='+today;
         console.log('cookie has been created');
     } else {
         alert('cookie already exist!');
     }
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

On refresh of the page, cookie is recognized however
for example, I change my url from *www.mywebsite.com/en/* to  *www.mywebsite.com/ru/*
(for language purposes) cookie has been created again.

I would like to ask what I am missing on this part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the '`path`' part of the cookie to '`/`'. Then it will Work for all paths.

```
document.cookie = "username=John Smith; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
```

Witout the path, the cookie will be set for the current path only.

Comment: Thank you! I just change like this -> document.cookie = 'onedaycookie='+today+'; path=/'; and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this code

```
window.cookie = {
set: function(c_name, value, exdays, path = '/') {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : ("; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString())) + "; path=" + path;
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
},
get: function(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
};
```

And you can check like this:

```
if("undefined" !== typeof cookie.get('lang')){
     //cookie is not set
     cookie.set('lang', 'en', 1);
}else{
     //cookie is set
}
```